# How to work properly with bootstrap in MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Immediately I apologize for my English, please help me figure out how to work with the bootstrap drop-down element in an MVC5 application?

The essence of the question is as follows, there is an application on MVC 5, it has a button with drop-down elements, but it does not work, here is the BundleConfig code

```
public class BundleConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
                "~/Scripts/messages_ru.js",
                "~/Scripts/methods_ru.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.options.validate.js"
            ));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                 "~/Content/css/Styles.css",
                 "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                 "~/Content/site.css",
                 "~/Content/newStyle.css"
             ));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery-ui").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.4.js",
                "~/Scripts/v2/jquery-1.9.1.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.min.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput.add.js",
                "~/Scripts/select2.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.multiple.select.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery-ui.datepicker.add.js"
            ));
        }
    }
```

Here is the code of the button itself in View

```
<button class="button dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Button_1
    <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    @foreach (var type in Enum.GetValues(typeof(REPORT_TYPE)).Cast<REPORT_TYPE>())
        {
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">@type.GetDescription()</a></li>
        }
</ul>
```

And here is the script connection code in the same View

```
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

But when you click on the button, the list does not open, who can tell me what I made a mistake?

Update 1:
If you connect the following scripts, then everything works fine, but they are designed for Bootstrap 4 versions, and I need for 5

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: A lot of issues here, why are you bundling but not using the bundles?

Comment: @mxmissile Could you clarify which packages you are talking about?  if about bootstrap, then it is installed

Comment: Your code: `<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>` isnt using bundling.

Comment: @mxmissile could you write more?  or give an example?